# Which apps are shown in launchpad? (how to flag them?) - Mavericks

Tags: macos, launchpad

Since Mavericks I think, launchpad decides on it's own which apps should be shown in. For example, the uninstaller apps of the adobe apps are hidden by default in Mavericks. In Mountain Lion they were shown.

Why am I interested in?
I installed an app in "Applications" folder, but it's not shown in launchpad.
I tried the following: `sudo rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db`
In the newly created database the app is not shown as well.

So is there a possibility that the developers flagged that app falsely as hidden like the uninstaller apps of the adobe apps?
If so, how could I fix that?
If not, same question. ;)

Comment: Check http://chaosspace.de/launchpad-control . (warn: me personally never tried it)

Comment: Unfortunately the app is not shown in launchpad control and there's no option to add an app.

Comment: What app is it? Might help us in finding the solution...

Comment: Roccat Kone XTD Driver, http://www.roccat.org/Support/Gaming-Mice/ROCCAT-Kone-XTD/#crb_2

Answer (score 1):

Move the application out of the applications folder, restart launchpad (either log out/log in or in terminal write `killall Dock`). Then move back the application to the applications folder.

Comment: Does not work, unfortunately.